# Nosetests and classmethods

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.5, nose

I am getting a strange error when I run `nosetests`:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Extract test data from tarball.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: extract_test_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'calling_file'
```

The code in question is split over two files:

tests/core.py

```
class CoreTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def extract_test_data(cls, calling_file, base='data', name_only=False):
        """Extract test data from tarball.
           ...
        """
        ...
```

tests/.../test_this.py

```
class TestThis(core.CoreTestCase):
    """Run some tests."""

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.TESTDAT_DIR = cls.extract_test_data(__file__)
```

The imports, etc., work correctly, and `unittest` does not have any trouble. But for some reason, `nose` is mangling the call.

I've tried all of the following:

```
cls.TESTDAT_DIR = cls.extract_test_data(calling_file=__file__)
cls.TESTDAT_DIR = cls.extract_test_data(cls,__file__)
cls.TESTDAT_DIR = cls.extract_test_data(cls, calling_file=__file__)
```

but then I still get an odd assortmenterrors:

```
TypeError: extract_test_data() got multiple values for argument 'calling_file'
AttributeError: type object 'TestThis' has no attribute 'TESTDAT_DIR'
```

Comment: Try renaming `extract_test_data` to something without the word `test` in it such as `extract_tst_data`. By default, nosetests looks for any function/method with the word `test` in it and treat them as tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nose` is trying to run `extract_test_data` like it's a unit test. Rename it to exclude the token `test` or add this to `extract_test_data`:

```
from nose.tools import nottest

class CoreTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

@nottest
@classmethod
def extract_test_data(cls, calling_file, base='data', name_only=False):
    """Extract test data from tarball.
       ...
    """
    ...
```

EDIT: [link](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#writing-tests) to the docs where it is explained that, by default, the `testMatch` regular expression will run any function that `has test or Test at a word boundary or following a - or _`

Comment: I thought it only tested methods that started with test...or is that just `unittest`?

Comment: By default ([link](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#writing-tests)) it will run any function that `has test or Test at a word boundary or following a - or _`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks!